# simple_html_dom - str_get_html bool(false)

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. 
Есть две ссылки и обе доступны с браузера.
На парсере стоит simpleHTMLDOM и страницы загружаются multiCurl'ом и меняется кодировка.

```
$link="http://sait.ru/bla/bla/";
$dataAdsPage=$curl->createCurl(array($link),$params);
$dataAdsPage[$link] = iconv("windows-1251", "UTF-8", $dataAdsPage[$link]);
```

Потом пытаюсь получить контент

```
$htmlOneAds = str_get_html($dataAdsPage[$link]);
```

`$htmlOneAds` - возвращает `bool(false)` ,а на второй ссылке нормально .

Но если вывести саму страницу в браузер

```
var_dump($dataAdsPage[$link]);
```

то страница нормально открывается.

Где искать проблему ? ведь страницы идентичны по структуре, только содержание разное ..

Спасибо !

Comment: немного еще поразмыслив, подумал, что может ошибки в html могут влиять на получение данных ? Просто прогнал в валидаторе и на двух этих страницах разное количество ошибок